# Update Panel in Sharepoint 2013 WebPart

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, sharepoint, updatepanel

I have kinda of a shopping page, with 2 different GridViews: gridProducts and gridCart.
gridProducts is where I have my products listed, and I have a button in each line called "Add to cart". When this button is clicked, I just add this product to gridCart.
Is there any way to use Update Panel to stop the post backs from refreshing the page everytime I click a button?
And also, can I set focus on my gridCart after I click "Add to cart"?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This works as described in the MSDN Articel Using the [ASP.NET UpdatePanel Control with Data-Bound Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386452.aspx)